# ESlint throws an error with my code here but I can't understand the problem

Tags: reactjs, eslint

After completing a few programming courses I have decided to make my own application. However, I have hit a brick wall and don't understand how to get around it. As you can see I have created a fake cart to use as part of my app for people to order food. however when sorting out my cart function I have the following error which I don't understand and as a result my application is showing as blank on chrome. any help is much appreciated as I am a beginner.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4Z96S.png)

again I am a beginner so any guidance is helpful :)

Comment: btw, if you click the name of the rule in the tooltip (no-unused-vars) it will link you to the documentation for that rule, which has much more details.  https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars

Answer (score 0):

ESLint says you never use variable you've created. Once you do something with it, the warning will gone.

For examle:

```
const cart = fakeCart;
return <div>
  <Link to='/menu'>Back to menu /</Link>
  <h2>Yourcart,%NAME%</h2>
  {cart.map(item) => <div>{item.name}</div>}
  <div>
    <Link to='/order/new'>Order pizzas</Link>
    <button>Clear cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```